# How to display numbers in reverse order using seq(1)?

Tags: command-line, seq

I have iterate over numbers in various order. I am able to display them in increasing order, even with steps like:

```
$ seq --separator="," 1 10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
$ seq --separator="," 1 2 10
1,3,5,7,9
```

I am also able to display them in reverse order, neither continuous nor step wise.

```
$ seq --separator="," 10 1   
$ seq --separator="," 10 2 1
```

No output for above commands.

My shell details:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Let me know how I would be able to display the numbers in descending order?

Comment: For future readers, `seq` is a completely nonstandard tool and there is no guarantee that any two implementations will be the same. If you need to write a loop that iterates backwards over numbers in bash, use `for ((i=$max;i>=0;i--)) …` or the like.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

use negative increment

```
seq -s, 10 -2 1
10,8,6,4,2
```

Answer (score 29):

In general, you don't want to use `seq`, it's not portable (even among standard Linux environments). If you're using ksh, zsh, or bash4+, you can use brace expansion:

```
echo {10..1..2} | tr " " ,
10,8,6,4,2
```

Comment: That's short and quick, but I am on older bash version.

Comment: Sweet answer, but there's some irony when you point out `seq` is nonstandard and then use bash-4-only brace expansion. ;)

Comment: @kojiro - No argument to be honest ;-) My main concern is not one of whether the command exists (that may or may not matter depending on whether the script is being distributed/etc), but whether the command executes as is expected by the author. bash4's brace expansion almost has that guaranteed (if it works, it works as you expect), whereas `seq` doesn't.

Comment: Why is it not portable? Do you have sources or proofs? I'm interested.

Answer (score 15):

Another way in pure bash, ksh or zsh:

```
for ((i=10;i>0;i-=2)) ; do echo -n "$i," ; done
```

A pure POSIX sh way:

```
i=10
while [ "$i" -gt 2 ]; do printf "$i,"; i=$((i-2)); done
echo "$i"
```

Comment: `for`'s second expression should be the test and the third the step.

Answer (score 7):

Now, standard POSIX ones:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i = 10; i > 0; i -= 2) print i}' | paste -sd , -
```

(interestingly, with `mawk` (and to a lesser extent `gawk` as well) a lot faster than GNU `seq` for `i = 10000000` instead of `i = 10`)

Or

```
i=10; set --
while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; do
  set -- "$@" "$i"
  i=$(($i - 2))
done
IFS=,
echo "$*"
```

(would only be more efficient with small numbers of iterations, especially with `bash`)

Or

```
echo 'for(i=10;i>0;i-=2) i' | bc | paste -sd , -
```

(which would support numbers of any size, but note that past a certain number of digits (numbers greater than 10<sup>70</sup> in the POSIX locale at least), lines would be wrapped with backslashes)

Comment: In GNU bc, you can avoid the line wrap by setting `BC_LINE_LENGTH=0` in the environment. No such luck on other implementations.

Comment: Why use the positional arguments rather than loop around `s=$s,$i` or call `echo -n`/`echo \c`/`printf`?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', `printf` is not guaranteed to be builtin, and `echo` can't be used here unless you know the exact  variant you have (POSIX without XSI leaves the behaviour unspecified if the first argument is `-n` or any argument contain backslashes). `s=$s,$i` and stripping the last `,` or not adding it on the first run would be an option yes.

Answer (score 5):

Try with:

```
   seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```

Example:

$ seq 10 -1 1

Answer (score 4):

You can reverse the order using `tac` (cat in reverse). Even if `seq` should behave differently on various system, I think the following should be as portable as possible:

```
$ seq 1 10 | tr '\012' ',' | sed 's/,$//'; echo
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
$ seq 1 10 | tac | tr '\012' ',' | sed 's/,$//'; echo
10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I often loop over months and find the `-w` option useful (to preserve the two digits).

```
for i in $(seq -w 12 -1 01); do echo $i; done
```

I’m not sure why the `-s,` was used in the original reply

Comment: (1) You should always quote all shell variable references unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.  So, in this example, you should say `echo "$i"`.  (2) Why not say just `seq -w 12 -1 01` ?  Why add the complexity of a shell loop? (See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/80216))  (3) [watael’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64864/80216) uses  `-s,` because it is the short form of `--separator=","`, which is used in the question. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) This (your post, above) isn’t really an answer to this question because it doesn’t say anything *relevant to what the question is asking* that isn’t already in [watael’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64864/80216).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `seq 1 20 | sort -nr`; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: (1) You should always quote all shell variable references unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.  So, in this example, you should say `echo "$i"`.  (2) Why not say just ``seq 1 20 | sort –nr`` ?  Why add the complexity of a shell loop? (See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/80216))  (3) `sort` is typically O(_N_  log _N_).  `tac`, as used in [hlovdal’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64975/80216), may be O(_N_), and therefore preferable.